# how to map a foreign key in a table that should have multiple tables?

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I have the following table,

Id
EntityType
EntityId
Message

Depending on what the EntityType is, it will be mapped to a different table

if the EntityType is 1, then the Mapping Table is Table1
if the EntityType is 2, then the Mapping table is Table2

How can I create a a map configuration in Entity frame work?

I am using MVC4 and EF5

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar design question and I couldn't find a (clean) way with EF to do it.  If you think about the underlying database, it would be single field that is a foreign key that would reference different tables - is that even possible?

There are two alternative approaches that I can suggest.  First, you could define optional relationships:

```
public class EntityTypeMap
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityType1 EntityType1 { get; set; }
    public int? EntityType1Id { get; set; }

    public virtual EntityType2 EntityType2 { get; set; }
    public int? EntityType2Id { get; set; }

    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

The second (better) option is to create separate models, but derive from the same base class:

```
public class BaseMap
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Message { get; set; }
}

public class EntityType1Map : BaseMap
{
    public virtual EntityType1 EntityType1 { get; set; }
    public int? EntityType1Id { get; set; }
}

public class EntityType2Map : BaseMap
{
    public virtual EntityType2 EntityType2 { get; set; }
    public int? EntityType1Id { get; set; }
}
```